# Python 3 não retornando float

Tags: python-3.x

Comecei a estudar python 3 e estava fazendo uns exercícios, até que me deparei com algo inesperado, não consigo receber um float como resposta. Segui tudo o que estava no exercício e mesmo assim recebo um integer.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Evite colocar imagens, coloque o código na pergunta.

Comment: Invés de `%i` use `%f`

Comment: Vlw pela ajuda cara.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Percebi que você colocou `"%i"` nas linhas 12 e 16, isto não é para mostrar valor do tipo integer.

Comment: Era esse o problema. Vlw pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Nas linhas em que estão colocados os **'prints'** de resultado basta trocar a codificação para:

```
 print("Media %f"%media)
```

Essa formatação irá permitir que você exiba o conteúdo em *Float*

nesse [link](https://www.codecademy.com/pt-BR/forum_questions/548ce2bb76b8feee350056d0) você pode conferir também outras funções que são utilizadas dessa mesma forma!